# How to create command to make custom Indicator Function

Tags: macros

So, I've found [this](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/proba/proba.pdf) package for common probability items in LaTeX and the very last entry is a "customizable" indicator function in which one simply inputs the variable (e.g. x) and it returns \mathbf{1}_{{x}}. I want to be able to make different indicator functions based on the inputs e.g. indicator functions where the set is {0,1,2,3,...} or maybe [0, \infty).

Is there anyway to make a LaTeX function that will do this for me, for specified inputs (parenthesis, or square brackets or braces and the elements of the set)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you would your exact input to be like, but `\newcommand{\vind}{\mathb{1}_{#1}}` can be used with any *set* you specify such as `\vind{\{1\}}`, `\vind{[0,\infty)}`, etc.